# Angular: Not able to access variables in controller using service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller

I am trying to share a variable between a controller and a function. But i get an error from the controller, saying this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSet' of undefined
```

I have gone through numerous tutorials, but don't know where am I going wrong. 
My service code is like this:

```
app.service('shareData', function() {

    var selected = ["plz", "print", "something"];

    var putSet = function(set) {
        selected = set;
    };

    var getSet = function() {
        return selected;
    };

    return {
        putSet: putSet,
        getSet: getSet
    };
});
```

I am able to reach `selected` from my function defined like this:

```
setDisplay = function($scope, $mdDialog, shareData) {

    console.log(shareData.getSet()); // this is working

    $scope.selected = shareData.getSet();
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
};
```

My controller is like this:

```
app.controller('topicController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'shareData',
function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, $mdToast, shareData) {

    console.log(shareData.getSet()); // NOT WORKING

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had extra `$mdToast` in your `topicController` controller's factory function, you need to remove it.

The reason behind it was not working is, currently you had 4 dependency mentioned in array like `['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'shareData', function` & then you are using its instance inside the function next to DI array. Inside that function you had actually 5 dependencies where `$mdToast` extra. So behind the scene what happening is `$scope` of function hold an value of `'$scope'` DI array likewise you go right to left. But when it comes to `$mdToast`(in controller function) it was holding a value of `'shareData'`(of DI array) & then the next parameter `shareData` get nothing.

```
app.controller('topicController', ['$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'shareData', 
      function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, shareData) { //<--removed $mdToast
    console.log(shareData.getSet());
  }
]);
```

> **NOTE:** You are using [DI inline array annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), so the sequence in which dependency are injected in array, in same sequence you should
>   inject then in underlying factory function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my precious time! But i am not getting the exact reason why I was not able to access it and removing $mdToast did the magic

Comment: @jAYANTYADAV I updated my answer, with in detail explain.. I think it would help you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again! Btw, what is a DI array? I mean full form.

Comment: Now it seems logical! and not magical. Thanks for clearing my concepts :)