# AngularJS Service Undefined When Injected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Stackoverflow has numerous questions under this title but I'm going through each one and not seeing what I'm doing meaningfully differently. More to the point, this isn't my only service, and the rest of them work.

My service:

```
(function () {    
    var envService = function ($location) {    
        //Removed           
        return {
            //Removed for SO, was simply an object of functions    
    }    
    var module = angular.module('passwordResetApp');
    module.factory('envService', ['$location', envService]);
}());
```

My app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('passwordResetApp', ['ngRoute', 'AdalAngular', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.selection']);
app
    .config([
            '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/home',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .when('/PasswordReset',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/passwordReset.html',
                            controller: 'ResetRequestController as vm',
                            //requireAdLogin: true,
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .when('/UserSearch',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/userSearch.html',
                            controller: 'UserSearchController as vm',
                            //requireAdLogin: true,
                            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                        })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
                adalProvider.init(
                    {
                        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
                        tenant: 'Removed for SO',
                        clientId: 'Removed for SO',
                        requireADLogin: false,
                        //anonymousEndpoints: [
                        //    '/'
                        //],
                        //endpoints: [
                        //    '/'
                        //],
                        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
                        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                        // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
                    },
                    $httpProvider
                );

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            }
        ]
    );

app.directive('header',
    function() {
        return {
            //Attribute, not element
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/views/_header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController as vm',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        }
    });

app.directive('footer',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/views/_footer.html',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true
        }
    });

app.run([
    '$route', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location',
    function ($route, $http, $rootScope) {
        $http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        $rootScope.getUrlPath = function (url) {
            return baseUrl + url;
        };
    }
]);
}());
```

And the controller attempting to have the service injected:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';    
    var app = angular.module('passwordResetApp');    
    var headerController = function ($scope, $location, envService, adalService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.currentUser = {};
        vm.environment = envService.getEnvironment();

        vm.changeView = function(view) {
            $location.path(view);
        };

        vm.login = function () {
            adalService.login();
        };

        vm.logout = function () {
            adalService.logOut();
        };
    };

    app.controller('HeaderController', ['adalAuthenticationService', headerController]);    

}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject all the dependencies in DI array, in order to use them in controller function. Make sure the sequence should not get messed up.

```
app.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$location', 'envService', 'adalService', headerController]);
```

Comment: That absolutely fixed it. I'll accept it once SO's 13-minute timer lets me. I've not done that, though, in my other controllers that use my other custom services. Just for my conceptual understanding, do you know why I was able to have those services injected without specifying their string names in the `app.controller()` method?

Comment: actually you could read up on my [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37968899/2435473) on similar question, let me know if you still don't get what you want. Thanks :)

Comment: the order was the thing